# Take a list from selected number

Tags: python, pandas

I want to build a chart, in X I saved the indexes of the table, and for Y I need to save the list of numbers from the selected column into it, but since the style table type attribute loc does not work, and there is also a multi-index, how can this be done? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmMvu.png)

I translated the table into a DataFrame, but then the numbers with percentages are converted to str format, and you can’t build a chart from them

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post images (or links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted directly into the question and [formatted properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). By posting images we are not able to copy your code to reproduce it. Also, it is not searchable so others can find your question easily. For more, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/6045800)

Comment: You can convert the strings back to a float using `float(percent_string.strip('%'))` given a string `percent_string`.